# Take Invisible Layout's Screenshot Programmatically In Android

Tags: android, screenshot, screen-capture

I Want To Implement Share Functionality in my App.And I Want To Share Multiple Product At A Time For That I Have To Take Screenshot Of All Layout.

Any Idea About It.

Comment: try to create your layout as a bit map image and store it  into sdcard and share that image@RAMU PAL

Comment: Can You Give me Demo Of How To Create Bitmap Of Layout

Answer (score 0):

Try THIs:

```
<uses-permission   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 


            viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int i) {
                // here put belowcode
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {
                }
            });
```

step1:

```
 Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(yourLyout.getWidth(), yourLyout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                 int weight,height;
                 weight =  yourLyout.getWidth();
                 height =  yourLyout.getHeight();
                 Bitmap cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(weight, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                 Canvas c = new Canvas(cs);
          c.drawBitmap(b,0,0,null);                  
           yourLyout.draw(c);
```

step2

```
      //First we get the root of sdcard/or ExternalStorage and then create a folder named photoEmail in sdcard by using mkdirs() method.

          Random generator = new Random();
          int n = 10000;
          n = generator.nextInt(n);

         String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/PhotoEmail";
                 File file = new File(root); 
                 file.mkdirs();
        //Name the image file in sdcard with images.png

         //File file1 = new File(root + "/" +"images"+n".png");
         //Now open the file and compress our bitmap image and make the file image file with png ow Open

        fos = new FileOutputStream(file1); 
        if (fos != null) {
        cs.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
         fos.close();
         }
```

step3:

```
 Intent picMessageIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
 picMessageIntent.setType("message/rfc822");#sthash.zPwDJd6s.dpuf
 File downloadedPic = new File("/sdcard/PhotoEmail/images.png")                
 picMessageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(downloadedPic));
  startActivityForResult(picMessageIntent, 1);
```

Comment: I Have To Use Weather ViewPager Or Inflater  For Showing Purpose

Comment: you mentioned invisible layout thats why i give this method

Comment: I Have To Take Screenshot Of Viewpager's All Item

Comment: ya ok no problem you just give your    layout.draw(c);instead of inflator i will edit my answer and post@RAMUPAL

Comment: Can You Upload Full Demo Sir !!

Comment: try above answer,if this answer not working please let me know i will give another answer@RAMUPAL

Comment: I Have 5 items It Takes Only Two Layout Screen Shot When After Scrolling All It Takes All ScreenShots How To Take Screenshot Of All Layout Without Scrolling

Comment: I think you have using view pager @RAMUPAL

Comment: Yes I Am Using ViewPager How TO Take All Screenshot Of Viewpager's Layout

Comment: then you have put the code on ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener @RAMUPAL

Comment: sir i am new to android can yo have demo of it

Comment: can u post your screen shot@RAMUPAL

Comment: are you using  slidingTabLayout@RAMUPAL

Comment: I Am Just Using Simple ViewPager